# Coleman CT200U EX starts when dies

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, small-engine, mini-bike, coleman

I initially was putting a new carb on but decided to just keep the stock one. I have put it all back on. But when I started it it instantly when full throttle. So I did some research and learned about the static governor. I adjusted that and now the bike starts then dies like i turned off the power. What do I do?? I feel I I’ve done everything and I almsot just wanna give up

Comment: I guess I'd expect it to stop when you turn off the power.  Perhaps you meant to ask something else.

Comment: @jwh20  The OP didn’t say that it dies when he turns off the power, he said that it dies like when turning off the power (re-worded).

Comment: Did you remove the original carb, then replace it?  What exactly did you do?